# how to add ImageButton in title bar

Tags: android

I am trying to add an `ImageButton` at right side of title bar of activity in Android, but when I execute application it gives error `Unfortunately app stopped`. Kindly help:

**custom_title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.abc.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.abc.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in log?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: the button is not displayed in title bar. no error at all

Answer (score 0):

Replace android:layout_height in the RelativeLayout:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: button is not displayed

Comment: Hmm...Just a wild guess...what happens if you add the following into your theme.xml:

     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

Answer (score 0):

Follow these guides from the Android Developer site and you will be a master! 
[Adding the App Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

Comment: I have followed that. But the question is why this code is not working?

Comment: No sir you have not, you have attempted to perform witchcraft to re-invent the wheel:
`this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);`

Use instead:
`Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);`